# Updating/overwriting multiple layers within a feature layer in ArcGIS Online from a fgdb containing all the new feature classes

Tags: arcgis-online, feature-class, update, arcgis-python-api, hosted-feature-layer

I am looking for a method to upload and replace multiple layers in ArcGIS Online that are stored within a (hosted) feature layer. I have the  feature classes to be used to update (and identical in name) stored in a fgdb on my local drive.

Does anyone have any ideas or tips to a script that are able to perform what I am looking for? I am fairly new to scripting, and have not been able to find other suggestions that updates multiple layers in a feature layer and deletes the old ones.

Comment: I believe the right way is to truncate the hosted feature layer and then append your data. This link shows a variaton for AGOL: https://community.esri.com/docs/DOC-14843-overwrite-arcgis-online-feature-service-using-truncate-and-append

Comment: Thank you @carlos, but isn't that script for updating one feature class only? Or am I missing something?

Comment: That is true. It truncates the first layer of the hosted feature layer (see: fLyr = premiseLayer.layers[0] in Line 55). You would need to adjust the script to truncate the right layer and then append with the correct one from your gdb. Maybe you can truncate the whole hosted feature layer by removing the [0].